# Combine values of RACSignal(s) but only triggered when the specific signal sends the next value (ReactiveCocoa)

Tags: objective-c, reactive-cocoa

I combine three signals together to get the latest values, but I only want the subscription is only triggered when the value of the specific signal (`toppestStretchPercentageSignal`) is changed.

How to deal with it?

The subscription of the following code will be triggered when any value of those three signals is changed.

```
[[RACSignal
    combineLatest:@[contentOffsetDidChangeSignal,
                    toppestVisibleItemSignal,
                    toppestStretchPercentageSignal]]
    subscribeNext:^(RACTuple *tuple) {
        NSLog(@"need to be only triggered when toppestStretchPercentageSignal sends the next value");
    }];
```

---

Update:

Thank [jhosteny's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1498921/jhosteny) answer. It looks like I just need to add `sample:` method after `combineLatest:`, doesn't it?

```
[[[RACSignal
    combineLatest:@[contentOffsetDidChangeSignal,
                   toppestVisibleItemSignal,
                   toppestStretchPercentageSignal]]
    sample:toppestStretchPercentageSignal]
    subscribeNext:^(id x) {
        NSLog(@"update toppest item frame");
    }];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
[[RACSignal
     zip:@[toppestStretchPercentageSignal,
           [[RACSignal
               combineLatest:@[contentOffsetDidChangeSignal,
                               toppestVisibleItemSignal]]
            sample:toppestStretchPercentageSignal]]] subscribeNext:^(RACTuple *tuple) {
                RACTupleUnpack(NSNumber *toppestStretch, RACTuple *tuple2) = tuple;
                RACTupleUnpack(id contentOffset, id visibleItem) = tuple2;
            }];
```

See [this comment](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/issues/977#issuecomment-29434883) in the ReactiveCocoa issues section on GitHub.

Comment: I think there's one subtle problem with that. If you look at the sampler implementation, it always sends the last value from the receiver, and only after it's gotten at least one value from the receiver. So, you may miss one value and thereafter be sampling `toppestStretchPercentageSignal` value from event index X, but receiving it's value from event index X-1. I'd have to devise a test to check that though. Practically speaking, it might not be an issue for your code either. Perhaps a more experience RAC developer will weigh in on this point.